# Kotlin - Modifying Picasso's RequestCreator based on extension function arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, extension-function

I've an extension function to `ImageView` class. I've implemented some logic on how to load an image according to arguments passed. But here I'm stuck. 
These `fit()`, `centerCrop()` etc. return Picasso's `RequestCreator`, which I can't even construct (it has package-private constructor) in order to modify it later (based on arguments).
I just don't know how to do this. The only way I managed to do this is as you can see below (Be warned: your eyes'll start bleeding). I can't find a "normal", "good" way to do it.

So I'm asking you: how should I approach doing this?

```
fun ImageView.load(resId: Int, centerCrop: Boolean = true, fit: Boolean = true) {

// Improve this, there must be a better way

if (centerCrop && fit) {
    Picasso.get()
            .load(resId)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(this)
} else if (centerCrop && !fit) {
    Picasso.get()
            .load(resId)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(this)
} else if (!centerCrop && fit) {
    Picasso.get()
            .load(resId)
            .fit()
            .into(this)
} else if (!centerCrop && !fit) {
    Picasso.get()
            .load(resId)
            .into(this)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Kotlins also function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html):

```
fun ImageView.load(resId: Int, centerCrop: Boolean = true, fit: Boolean = true) {
    Picasso.get()
        .load(resId)
        .also { if (centerCrop) it.centerCrop() }
        .also { if (fit) it.fit() }
        .into(this)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!